# Return a boolean whether search term is partial match for data-tag

Tags: javascript

I have an input element and a lot of elements with data tags:

```
<div data-name="Axel Prüfer"></div>
<div data-name="The Kernel Brewery"></div>
...
```

When the user types into the input field it would show/hide any partial matches. Some examples of what a user enters into the input field could be:

```
'Axel', 'Axel Prüfer', 'Prüfer', 'axel Prüfer', 'pruf', 'axe'
```

Is there a way to return a boolean whether the search term is a partial match for each data tag? I was going to use `includes()` but that is case sensitive and won't match u to ü, for example. Could I use `RegEx` here or maybe `match()`?

Comment: `dataName.includes(search)` does *not* require the full term.

Comment: @Bergi Fair ;) I've updated my question.

Comment: For dealing with cases and umlauts you'll need to normalise both sides before comparing them. E.g. `dataName.toLowercase().includes(search.toLowercase())`, and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/990904/1048572) for dealing with umlauts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bergi mentions in the comments, you are mistaken about `includes`.  It works with partial result.  My guess is that the way you were going to use it was backwards: ie. input-value.includes(data-value), when the opposite is what you want.

Below is a working example of what you're trying to accomplish.

```js
document.querySelector('#input').addEventListener('keyup', e => {

  let dataDivs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-name]');
  let inputVal = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  for(let dd of dataDivs) {
    let dataVal = dd.attributes['data-name'].value.toLowerCase();
    dd.style.display = 
        inputVal === '' ? 'none'
      : dataVal.includes(inputVal) ? 'block' 
      : 'none';
  }
 
})
```

```html
<input id='input'/>
<div data-name="Axel Prüfer" style='display:none'>Axel Prüfer</div>
<div data-name="The Kernel Brewery" style='display:none'>The Kernel Brewery</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If browser supports `document.querySelectAll`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-name*="Axel"]')

// To return boolean
const found = document.querySelectorAll('[data-name*="Axel"]').length > 0
```

Otherwise use jQuery

```js
const found = $('[data-name*="Axel"]').length > 0
```

Refer to https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/ for more information. There are also other useful attribute selectors at well: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/, they work the same way for `document.querySelectAll()`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was hoping to use vanilla JS but also something that returns a boolean.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll()` is vanilla JavaScript works in browser. To return boolean simply do `const found = document.querySelectorAll('[data-name*="Axel"]').length > 0`